# Fedora and default permissions for initramfs

Tags: permissions, fedora, kernel, initramfs

I'm on Fedora 33 and I would like initramfs to be readable by any user after each kernel upgrade. How can I change its default permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
cat /etc/kernel/postinst.d/noreadirfs.sh

#! /bin/bash

chmod 640 /boot/initramfs*
```